# Reboot in middle of bash script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm writing a bash script to setup some services in Ubuntu. I require some system `reboot`s between some steps. The problem with this is running `reboot` interrupts the script as well. Is there a way for the script to persist and continue the setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145294/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your system. I can give an example for Ubuntu of what you can do.

Such a script should look something like this `/usr/local/bin/this_script`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f  /usr/share/this_script.progress ] ; then
    echo 1 >  /usr/share/this_script.progress
    cat > /etc/systemd/system/this_script.service <<EOF
[Unit]
Description=this script service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/this_script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
    systemctl enable this_script
    echo 2 >  /usr/share/this_script.progress
fi
progress=$(</usr/share/this_script.progress)

case $progress is
(1) echo "This should not happen!"
    ;;
(2) echo 3 >  /usr/share/this_script.progres
    action_for first stage
    reboot
    ;;
(3) echo 4 >  /usr/share/this_script.progres
    action_for second stage
    reboot
    ;;
(4) closing_actions
    systemctl disable this_script
    rm -f /usr/share/this_script.progres /etc/systemd/system/this_script.service
    ;;
esac
```

Note: untested; there may be some issues that I haven't thought of.